# unable to start Windows - hangs when loading classpnp.sys

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, boot

I'm using HP DL360p Gen8, I can not start my Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 server. When Welcome screen should appear I only see black screen and mouse pointer. When I'm trying safe mode it hangs trying to load "classpnp.sys".

I'm using "mirror-raid" + extra "spare" hdd installed, so I wonder how is it possible that i'm having troubles with corrupted files? What should I do? Should I reinstall Windows or there are other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily related to corrupted OS bits.  It might also be another problem.  Try updating the server's BIOS and testing the memory.  If you have USB devices attached remove them and try again.  Failing this, you'll probably have to reimage it.

If you happen to see constant disk activity while it is hung it might also be a bad RAID controller, backplane or cable, or a disk with a weird firmware bug, though for this particular issue that is less likely.

Comment: how to test the memory, should I use HP utility? Windows was started in 50% of cases after I've tried to tune some registry values (disabled and reenabled DCOM), and it finally unable to start after I performed "windows checkdisk". probably chkdsk is not compatible with raid...

Comment: The filesystem parts of the check should work just fine with RAID unless it happens that the RAID controller is bad, at which point it will behave oddly.  Also, if windows starts half the time, this points at a hardware issue.  If HP provides a diagnostic for the RAM go ahead and use it (I forget) - otherwise, memtest86+ is just as good.

Comment: thanks, do you know how can i fix existent windows server 2008 r2 installation? i've tried to load windows disk but it offers to either install a fresh copy or recovery using "image i created before", which i doesn't have...

Comment: If it's a hardware problem that isn't the right thing to do.  If it isn't and you have extensive OS corruption but you know the RAID controller is not bad, backup and reimage.

Comment: how can I access NTFS encrypted data on HDD if windows doesn't start?

Comment: You do keep backups, don't you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10077/discussion-between-javapowered-and-falcon-momot)